# How to transfer variables between consoles or devices?

Tags: python, network-programming

I have this python-script that I am trying to write where it is necessary to transfer a large amount of data between different consoles (running different instances of the same program). The idea is that eventually one could have two computers both running this python script and have a chat function while the program is exchanging some data in the background.

I am currently using the QTPY library to run the GUI and network-connections and have succeeded in sending text messages and abused the WebSocket.sendTextMessage() function to to sending some small packages back and forth.

I am wondering how to transfer numpy arrays using QTPY (or at this point anything). Further abuse of WebSocket.sendTextMessage() seems like it would be slow, inefficient and laborious to implement. If anyone knows how to transfer variables over the internet or simply have any sage-advise I would be more than happy to hear it!

Comment: One of the simpliest ways would be to to dump whatever variables you need into a JSON string, send them as a text and load on the other side back into objects. This of course would require special handling for any objects that are not directly serializable into JSON by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @matszwecja Can you post it as an answer such that I can mark your answer as the correct one?